# Weird issues styling a foreground to a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

Honestly not sure where I am going wrong here, but for whatever reason the foreground style seen below is not being applied to the datagrid.  I'm at a loss for this one as I really don't know how I would go about debugging the xaml.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgProperties" Background="#1E918D8D" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ItemsSource="{Binding CurFieldData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True">

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" >
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3535bb" />

            <!--<Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DiffState}" Value="Different">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3535BB" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>-->

        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property" FontSize="12"  Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="2*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Left Value" FontSize="12" Binding="{Binding LeftValue}"  Width="4*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Right Value" FontSize="12" Binding="{Binding RightValue}"  Width="4*"/>                                
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You can probably tell through the commented out trigger, but I originally planned on recoloring all entries in the grid that are marked as different (an enum in the code behind).  However, that wasn't working for me so I wanted to try and see if the style was being set at all, regardless of the trigger.

Does anybody see or know why this style is not being applied?

Comment: I copy pasted your Xaml and applied some items and the text is blue? so it seems to be working, are you sure ther is not anothet dataGrid style overriding the Foreground property

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working just fine, I have added my test code below incase it helps

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <DataGrid Name="dgProperties" Background="#1E918D8D" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=UI}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" >
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DiffState}" Value="Different">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property" FontSize="12"  Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="2*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Left Value" FontSize="12" Binding="{Binding LeftValue}"  Width="4*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Right Value" FontSize="12" Binding="{Binding RightValue}"  Width="4*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<GridItem> items = new ObservableCollection<GridItem>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new GridItem { Name = "StackOverflow" + i, LeftValue = i % 4, RightValue = i % 2 });
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GridItem> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set { items = value; }
    }

}

public class GridItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int LeftValue { get; set; }
    public int RightValue { get; set; }

    public DiffState DiffState
    {
        get
        {
            if (LeftValue == RightValue)
            {
                return DiffState.Same;
            }
            return DiffState.Different;
        }
    }
}

public enum DiffState
{
    Different,
    Same
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What did you change to fix it?

Comment: @GarryVass, I changed nothing. his code works as expected, I only posted my test code incase he wants to test independantly from his application as it may help him find the issue.

Comment: AH!  Got it!  I will add another in that same vein.

Answer (score 0):

The styling of a DataGridRow can be confounded by settings that occur higher up the object graph, especially the Alternating Row Background.  As shown in sa_ddam213's answer, the Xaml works when nothing else is declared.  So purely as a diagnostic accelerator, add these four lines to the DataGrid declaration...

```
  RowBackground="Transparent"
  Background="Transparent"
  AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"
  Foreground="Transparent"
```

And then inspect your foreground property and its trigger.  You can then mutate those four properties on the DataGrid to identify the confounding influence (and then remove it).